# win32 API Logon user when interactive login is not allowed

Tags: c#, winapi, authentication, wcf-security, impersonation

I'm using [win32 API Logon user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) on c# in order to impersonate a wcf channel. 
The problem when service is running in a machine where the admin removed all the users (except admin) from ["Allow logon locally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957044(v=ws.10).aspx)" the impersonation fails. 
How can I impersonate the call if GPO does not allow "Allow logon locally" (Interactive login)?

aditional info:

- I tried to use all methods (Interactive, NewCredentials, Network...)
- The service running web application serving all organization users.
  The admin does not allow to add all users to "Allow logon locally" (typically 
  all organization users are there)
- The the WCF channel impersonation is a legacy code and cannot be changed.

Comment: Perhaps it's not possible. Seems like the sysadmin has explicitly blocked your task.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of, If this is the case I'm looking for a workaround